# Remote debugging over USB with Android Phone is stuck in "Waiting for browser..."

Tags: firefox, remote-debugging

I am following the guide provided by MDN to `remotely debug`. I have made sure that I allowed USB Debugging on my Android phone. The version of my PC's Firefox is `72.0.1` and the version of my phone's is `68.4.1`.

I've done the instructions below:

> ```
> Enable Developer settings on your Android device.
> Enable USB debugging in the Android Developer settings.
> Enable Remote Debugging via USB in the Advanced Settings in Firefox on the Android device.
> Connect the Android device to your computer using a USB cable.
> ```

My device has been correctly detected. However, it's stuck in `"Waiting for browser..."` I have opened a new tab, which I want to debug, on my phone's Firefox. How do I fix that problem?

For reference, here's the picture of `"Waiting for browser..."`:
[image: Waiting for browser]

**EDIT**

It turns out that I forgot to enable `Remote debugging via USB` in Firefox on the Android device.

Comment: Coudl someone please help me with this question?

Comment: My coworker and I are having the same issue :(

Comment: @user763648 When you guys figure out the solution, could you please post it here?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it by enabling remote debugging in Firefox for Android (`Settings > Advanced > Remote debugging via USB`).

[image: Android Advanced Settings]

Comment: FWIW, I was looking for this option for a while on an older device, but found out that it's disabled on SDK < 23 (i.e. anything below Android 6.0).

Comment: FYI in newer versions of FF you find the direct entry already in the `Settings`.